# How to design my subview "layers"?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm working on an app that lets the user play dress up by adding things like hats, hair, eyes, etc. to a body. The user basically drags the item from a menu, and I instantiate the graphic onto the screen with some form off "`addSubview: or insertSubview:belowSubview:/aboveSubview:`".

The question is, some items should always appear below others. For example, "eyes" (blue,brown,green) graphics should always appear above "eyeballs" (various eye shapes and expressions). However, I don't force the user to follow any process, they can drag and drop as they please, so addSubview: may not be appropriate, but maybe insertSubview:belowSubview:/aboveSubview: would be, depending on how you could reference the item you want to add below or above.

Ideally, I'd follow a stack like this:
Accessories > Hair Styles > Eyebrows > Eyeballs > Eyes...etc. Does anyone have design ideas on how to implement this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your view hierarchy look like this:

```
self.view
├─ self.accessoriesView
│  ├─ braceletView
│  └─ toeRingView
├─ self.hairStylesView
│  ├─ blondeWigView
│  └─ hairClipView
├─ self.eyebrowsView
│  └─ archedEyebrowView
├─ self.eyeballsView
│  ├─ bloodshotEyeballView
│  └─ regularEyeballView
├─ self.eyesView
│  └─ greenEyesView
├─ etc.
```

When the user drags out a hair style from the menu, add the new hair style view as a subview of `self.hairStylesView`.  When the user drags out green eyes from the menu, add the new eyes view as a subview of `self.eyesView`.

Views that are later in the `subviews` array are "closer" to the user - they paint over views earlier in the `subviews` array.  So if you create the grouping views in code, you can just use `addSubview:` if you add them in the correct order.  Or if you set up your views in a nib, you can put them in the correct order in the nib outline.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. However, by implementing this, you now have a stack of UIViews on the ViewController's view. If your gesture recognizers on created in another class, you need a way to access them. I used hitTest on a subclass to let those views pass touches through to the next subview if nothing was touched: http://vectorvector.tumblr.com/post/2130331861/ignore-touches-to-uiview-subclass-but-not-to-its